# Problems in retrieving UTF-8 body from put request using a JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, utf-8, jaxb, jax-rs

I am trying to send the following utf-8 encoded XML to a rest api that is implemented using JAX-RS in Java.

The XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<incomingData><Text>καλημέρα</Text></incomingData>
```

Then  I am trying to parse data using the following REST API call:

```
@PUT()
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public void print(@QueryParam("printerID") int printerID,
                  InputStream requestBodyStream) {

    IncomingData StudentData = null;
    try {    
        JAXBContext jaxbContext =
          JAXBContext.newInstance(IncomingData.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StudentData = (IncomingData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(requestBodyStream);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(new String(StudentData.Text.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In order to easily parse the XML contents, I am also using this JAXB annotated class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class IncomingData {
    @XmlElement(name = "Text")
    String Text = new String();
}
```

However the contents of the `Text` XML tag is still displayed as `?????` when I am printing it's contents as a UTF-8 encoded string.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why this: `new String(StudentData.Text.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`? Doesn't `StudentData.Text` contain your String? Besides: `StudentData` is not a valid variable name. They start with lower-case letters or `_`.

Comment: I wrote this new String(StudentData.Text.getBytes(), "UTF-8") in order to encode the contents of the Text variable in UTF8. StudentData is valid variable name since the compiler does not protest... except if you mean that it is not best practice to name your variables with capitals which is out of my concern at the moment...

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html for rules and conventions concerning variable names.

Comment: Ok... this is getting a bit ridiculous. The way I am coding is surely not the best practice, but your answers do not SOLVE MY PROBLEM... SO, please provide ideas on how to solve the original problem, which was the goal of my question at the first place... Useless remarks about naming conventions remind me of grammar nazis...

Comment: Please note that here I'm not *answering* but *commenting* on your question. That's not the same. And please don't shout by using all-caps.

Comment: But I did not asked for comments... I've asked solutions as can be seen in my previous post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure your container encoding is set to UTF-8. Second, try writing output to file not to `System.out`, because maybe your output is already in UTF-8 but you 'out' cannot display UTF-8.

Comment: I've already added this line to my code in order to enforce output through the System to be encoded as utf-8   System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

Comment: @obelix Usually when UTF-8 is seen as `???` means that you not encoding it at all or viewing it with something that not supports UTF-8. Where does you `System.out` goes and how do you view it?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)` is tripping you up, and if you would be better with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)`.  I believe the encoding for `text/xml` is `US-ASCII`.

---

How are you sending your XML data?  Are you sure the data being sent is "UTF-8" encoded?  I tried your model with a standalone example and everything worked fine.

**Demo**

```
package forum12974953;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(IncomingData.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12974953/input.xml");
        IncomingData id = (IncomingData) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(id, System.out);
    } 

}
```

**input.xml (explicitly saved as UTF-8)/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<incomingData>
    <Text>καλημέρα</Text>
</incomingData>
```